# child class attribute different name

Tags: python

I want an attribute of a child class to have a different name than the same attribute of its parent class even though it means the same thing. For example, a parent class is Shape with attribute "height" and child class Circle with similar arttribute "Diameter". Below is a simplification of what I current have but I want the Circle class to use "diameter" instead of "height". What is the best way to handle this?

NOTE: I will inherit from Circle in another class that also needs to use "diameter" instead of "height". Thank you!

```
class Shape():
    def __init__(self, shape, bar_args, height):
        self.shape = shape
        self.height = height
        etc.

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, height, foo_args, shape='circle'):
    Shape.__init__(self, shape, height)
        self.height = height
        etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) which accesses the original attribute on read and write access:

```
class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, height, foo_args, shape='circle'):
        Shape.__init__(self, shape, height) # assigns the attributes there
        # other assignments
    @property
    def diameter(self):
        """The diameter property maps everything to the height attribute."""
        return self.height
    @diameter.setter
    def diameter(self, new_value):
        self.height = new_value
    # deleter is not needed, as we don't want to delete this.
```

If you want this behaviour very often and you find property handling with setter and getter too unhandy, you can go a step higher and [build](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) your own [descriptor class](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors):

```
class AttrMap(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, obj, typ):
        # Read access to obj's attribute.
        if obj is None:
            # access to class -> return descriptor object.
            return self
        return getattr(obj, self.name)
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        return setattr(obj, self.name, value)
    def __delete__(self, obj):
        return delattr(obj, self.name)
```

With this, you can then do

```
class Circle(Shape):
    diameter = AttrMap('height')
    def __init__(self, height, foo_args, shape='circle'):
        Shape.__init__(self, shape, height) # assigns the attributes there
        # other assignments
```

and the `diameter` descriptor will redirect all accesses to it to the named attribute (here: `height`).

Comment: glglgl: thank you very much for the quick reply. What if I create a grandchild class that inherits from Circle and I also want to use "diameter" instead of "height". Does this mean I have to do this same @property idea all over again? Thank you!

Comment: From a third property, you can access `diameter` and/or `height` as you like. All read accesses  to `diameter` are redirected to `height`, as well as all write accesses.

Comment: glglgl, that is very nice. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JasonLillywhite You'll thank me later. :-) (Preferrably by klicking on the check mark next to my answer, if it was the most helpful one.)