# Python - typechecking OK when error wouldn't be thrown otherwise?

Tags: python, oop

I have some Python classes that, if simplified, look like:

```
class base:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.value = v

    def doThings(self):
        print "Doing things."

    def doMoreThings(self):
        print "Doing more things."

    def combine(self, b):
        self.value += b.value

class foo(base):
    def showValue(self):
        print "foo value is %d." % self.value

class bar(base):
    def showValue(self):
        print "bar value is %d." % self.value
```

The `base` class contains methods (represented above by `doThings` and `doMoreThings`) which implement functionality common to both the `foo` and `bar` subclasses.  The `foo` and `bar` subclasses differ essentially in how they interpret the `value` field.  (Above, they only differ by what they show when printing it, but in my actual application, they do several other things which are more complicated.)  `base` can be thought of as "abstract":  users only ever work with `foo`s and `bar`s.  `base` exists only as a home for code common to its subclasses.

The method I want to ask about is `combine`, which lets you take two of these objects and make a third.  Because `foo` and `bar` interpret `value` differently, it doesn't make sense to `combine` two subclasses of different types:  you can `combine` two `foo`s to get a `foo` or two `bar`s to get a `bar` but not a `foo` and a `bar`.  Even so, the procedure for `combine` is the *same* for all subclasses, so it makes sense to have it factored out and defined in one place.

I would probably like to signal an error if a user tries to `combine` two incompatible objects, but I don't see a way to do this without introducing ugly typechecks.  Is it good practice to do this?  Or should I do the usual thing and not check, document the issue, and assume that the user won't try to use `combine` in a way that wasn't intended, even though such use would appear to "succeed" and return a garbage object instead of raising an error?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several approaches here:

1. Don't check anything and trust the user to do the right thing. Might be appropriate or dangerous, depending on the situation.
2. Check the type. You are right that it looks ugly, but is the easiest thing.
3. Don't have a `value`, but name them the way they are intended to have (`pressure`, `temperature`) and let them combine themselves.
4. Same as 3, but additionally have the subclasses have a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) which maps accesses to `.value` to their respective "real" value variable. This way, you can keep the .`__init__()`, but the `.combine()` will have to be done by every subclass.
5. Same as 4, but don't use `property`, but a self-crafted [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16173137/296974), I show how it could be done.

Answer (score 2):

Alter the combine method

```
def combine(self, b):
    if (not(self.__class__.__name__ == b.__class__.__name__)):
        raise TypeError("%s cannot combine with %s" % ( self.__class__.__name__, b.__class__.__name__))
    else:        
        self.value += b.value
```

Alternatively, alter the class definition for base to

```
class base(object):
```

and then a simpler, nicer, happier combine method is possible (thanks glglgl)

```
def combine(self, b):
    if (not(type(self) == type(b))):
        raise TypeError("%s cannot combine with %s" %
                        ( type(self), type(b) ))
    else:        
        self.value += b.value
```

Comment: Comparing `__class__.__name__` is IMHO very ugly. A much better way would be comparing `type(self) == type(b)` or using `isinstance(b, type(self))`.

Comment: @glglgl ``type(self) == type(b)`` is always true as both are ``instance``.  ``isinstance`` has the same problem.  Agree it's ugly but...

Comment: Ouch! Didn't see the OP uses old-style classes... then it's clear. (I try to avoid them wherever possible.) But with `isinstance` it should work woth old-style classes as well (just tested).

Comment: @glglgl yes, possibly the best solution would be to declare base an object and then use type(self) == type(b).  Editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

When I worked on production code that *shall not fail*, I used a decorator ensuring that a risky function will not explode, turn into a fireball and blow my whole system.

```py
def bulltproof(func):
    def _bulletproof(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            raise BulletproofError(exc)
        return result
    return _bulletproof
```

Use it like that:

```
@bulletproof
def some_risky_function():
    #....
```

And catch only one error:

```
try:
    some_risky_function()
except Bulletproof:
...
```

Instead of  raising the error you can return `None`, log error or turn it off for tests. Of course, this approach is useful when you want to ensure that your program will recover from error, but sometimes it's better to die than continue with error

Answer (score 0):

Since `.combine()` is conceptually doing completely different things depending on whether the objects are `foo` or `bar`, I think it makes sense NOT to have the function in the abstract parent, but to keep it in the derived classes. Even if it's the same code, combining two instances of `foo` would be a different operation from combining two instances of `bar`. If the code for `.combine()` is actually very lengthy, you could create a private method in the base class to do the work, but only call it from functions defined in the derived class.